# Rerender template using model (without going to server)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model which changes client side; i.e., dynamically changes what it outputs depending on what is typed into a search box. I currently have it set up that every time the search box changes, the model is `refresh`ed using `this.refresh()`.

This does what I want because it rerenders the template using a new model, but it also sends a request to the server for new model data.

**Is there any way to disable requesting new model data from the server?**

Comment: You don't need to use refresh. Please provide more information about how search box related to your model. And FYI you can use model in template without tweaking

Comment: May you could provide an [ember-twiddle](http://ember-twiddle.com/) to demonstrate the situation?